# MySQL many-to-many intersection using a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
People (pk: ID_PERSON)
Employees (pk: ID_EMPLOYEE)
Meetings (pk: ID_MEETING, fk: ID_PERSON, fk: ID_EMPLOYEE)
```

And I need to select people from meetings according to the following condition: "find all people who met with the Employee1 AND Employee2"

If I want to select filtering only by one Employee, then I do the following:

```
SELECT ID_PERSON FROM Meetings
WHERE ID_EMPLOYEE=:Employee1
```

But what is the most effective way to select people, who met at least two people? I can imagine something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID_PERSON
FROM
    Meetings
WHERE
    ID_EMPLOYEE=:Employee2
AND ID_PERSON IN
    (SELECT ID_PERSON FROM Meetings
     WHERE ID_EMPLOYEE=:Employee1)
```

But the subquery may return a giant amount of records. Is there any better way? Does there exist a single query solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with a self-join. To avoid duplicates you can use distinct.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(m1.ID_PERSON)
FROM
    Meetings m1, Meetings m2
WHERE
    m1.ID_EMPLOYEE=:Employee2
AND
    m2.ID_EMPLOYEE=:Employee1
AND
    m1.ID_PERSON = m2.ID_PERSON
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various solutions to this (common) problem. It can be solved with `EXISTS` subqueries:

```
SELECT
    p.id_person
FROM
    People AS p
WHERE
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
             FROM Meetings AS m 
             WHERE m.id_person = p.id_person
               AND m.id_employee = :Employee1) 
  AND 
    EXISTS ( SELECT 1
             FROM Meetings AS m 
             WHERE m.id_person = p.id_person
               AND m.id_employee = :Employee2
           ) ;
```

... or multiple `JOIN` to the `Meetings` table. (I assume) that a person can have more than one meeting with an employee, so if you use joins, there has to be a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` (as @popovitsj's answer)

Another solution is to have a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`. The query is more compact but it is often less efficient:

```
SELECT
    id_person
FROM
    Meetings AS m 
WHERE
    id_employee IN (:Employee1, :Employee2)
GROUP BY 
    id_person 
HAVING
    COUNT( DISTINCT id_employee ) = 2 ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason I cannot use sub-queries, but your second proposal works more efficient than @popovitsj's solution if to judge by MySQL's EXPLAIN. I'm not sure however, will it be still more efficient when I get more data in my db. Anyway, now I like both variants, and cannot consider which one to use :)

Comment: I checked my specific conditions (I have much more complicated query and this was just a part of it), so in my situation @popovitsj's query works better. But I'm sure there can be use-cases where your proposal will be better.

Comment: Efficiency depends on several things (indexes, data distributions, table sizes, etc.) I would suggest at least 2 indexes, on `(id_person, id_employee)` (for the last query) and on `(id_employee, id_person)` (for popovitsj and my 1st one.) But of course the suggestion may not be the best if the queries are more complex.